# jquery get the text inside <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this div

```
<div class="RestauranstSection">
    <label>
        Restaurant:
    </label>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="button" value="Search"/>
    <ul>
        <?php while ($row = $restaurants->fetch()) {
            ?>
            <li id="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
                <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want when press on any `li` elements to alert its text,

```
$(".RestauranstSection").on('click','li',function (){});
```

how please?

Comment: Did you read http://api.jquery.com/text/?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No I didn't

Comment: I don't want to be *that* guy, but seriously, [searching for `jquery get text of element`](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+get+text+of+element) brings http://api.jquery.com/text/ as first result, as well as other related SO questions.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
$(".RestauranstSection").on('click','li',function (){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: thank you very much, i will accept your answer, after 10 mins

Answer (score 5):

You just have to select the li and register for the click event like so

```
$(".RestauranstSection li").click(function (){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

(you also might want to spell check RestaurantsSection ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$(".RestauranstSection").on('click','li',function (){
    alert($(this).html())
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u899C/)

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: For reference, `html()` would display the HTML markup. If your list was `<li><strong>Hello</strong>, world!</li>`, the result of `html()` would be `"<strong>Hello</strong>, world!"` whereas  `text()` would be `"Hello, world!"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES2015 arrow function syntax for `click` callback, you may want to use `$(e.currentTarget).text()`

`$(".RestauranstSection li").click((e)=>{
    alert($(e.currentTarget).text());
});`